# Deriving properties?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Is there a way of declaring derived properties?

```
public class Vehicle {

    public VehicleType Type { get; set; }

}

public class Car : Vehicle {

    public CarType Type { get; set; }

}

public class VehicleType {}

public class CarType : VehicleType {}
```

so that when I call Car.Type; I only see car types?

Comment: A note on your current code: You've got two different `Type` properties, the one in `Car` is hiding the other, and ought to have the `new` keyword to clarify this (that it's not `override`-ing the other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. The `Type` property has to have the same type in both the base and the derived classes.

One way of doing this is using generics:

```
public class Vehicle<TVehicleType> where TVehicleType: VehicleType {

    public TVehicleType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle<CarType> {  }


Car car = new Car();
car.Type = new CarType();
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties can indeed be declared `abstract` or `virtual` on a base class and overridden by a derived class. But when using inheritance, you **cannot** change the input parameters or return type of the function/property.

If you find that you want a totally different type for the same property between the derived and the base, you may have a [design smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Perhaps inheritance isn't what you actually want.

If you still think you need something like this, you might be able to leverage [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx):

```
class Base<T>
{
    public virtual T MyProp { /* ... */ }
}

// Derived class that uses string for prop
class Derived1 : Base<string>
{
    public override string MyProp { /* ... */ }
}

// Derived class that uses int for prop
class Derived2 : Base<int>
{
    public override int MyProp { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public class Car : Vehicle {

    public CarType Type
    {
        get { return base.Type; }
        set { base.Type = value; }
    }
}
```

I would suggest not using the name "Type" because it's a reserved member already.